# Add Cordova plugins to Vue-Cordova?

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, plugins, vue.js

I'm trying to use [Vue-Cordova](https://github.com/kartsims/vue-cordova) along with [Cordova-plugin-file-opener2](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2) 
to open pdf's in ios/android apps.

Vue-Cordova defines plugins related to the device on the data property of the App vue instance:

```
  data: function () {
    return {
      cordova: Vue.cordova,
      plugins: {
        'cordova-plugin-camera': function () {
          if (!Vue.cordova.camera) {
            window.alert('Vue.cordova.camera not found !')
            return
          }
          Vue.cordova.camera.getPicture((imageURI) => {
            window.alert('Photo URI : ' + imageURI)
          }, (message) => {
            window.alert('FAILED : ' + message)
          }, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: Vue.cordova.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
          })
        },
         ....
```

I can access these properties on my ios simulator, but I am not able to access plugins that I install via the cordova-cli.  The Cordova object that should be exposed to call file-opener2 commands like:

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
    filePath, 
    fileMIMEType, 
    {
        error : function(){ }, 
        success : function(){ } 
    } 
);
```

has properties not included on the Vue.cordova instance.  When I try accessing them with:
`Vue.cordova.plugins.fileOpener2`
I get undefined.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to add plugins to Vue-Cordova, or possibly bypass it somehow?

EDIT:

My attempt at a solution doesn't work, but I feel I'm getting close.

I took the following steps:

1. cloned https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2 into the plugins folder of my cordova project
2. changed the following in `node_modules/vue-cordova/index.js`:

   function(module, exports, **webpack_require**) {

   ```
           'use strict';

   // list here all supported plugins
   var pluginsList = ['cordova-plugin-camera', 'cordova-plugin-device', 'cordova-plugin-geolocation', 'cordova-plugin-contacts', 'cordova-plugin-file-opener2'];

   exports.install = function (Vue, options) {

     // declare global Vue.cordova object
     Vue.cordova = Vue.cordova || {
       deviceready: false,
       plugins: []
     };

     // Cordova events wrapper
     Vue.cordova.on = function (eventName, cb) {
       document.addEventListener(eventName, cb, false);
     };

     // let Vue know that deviceready has been triggered
     document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
       Vue.cordova.deviceready = true;
     }, false);

     // load supported plugins
     pluginsList.forEach(function (pluginName) {
       var plugin = __webpack_require__(1)("./" + pluginName);
       plugin.install(Vue, options, function (pluginLoaded) {
         if (pluginLoaded) {
           Vue.cordova.plugins.push(pluginName);
         }
         if (Vue.config.debug) {
           console.log('[VueCordova]', pluginName, '→', pluginLoaded ? 'loaded' : 'not loaded');
         }
       });
     });
   };
   ```

   /***/ },
   /* 1 */
   /***/ function(module, exports, **webpack_require**) {

   ```
   var map = {
       "./cordova-plugin-camera": 2,
       "./cordova-plugin-camera.js": 2,
       "./cordova-plugin-contacts": 3,
       "./cordova-plugin-contacts.js": 3,
       "./cordova-plugin-device": 4,
       "./cordova-plugin-device.js": 4,
       "./cordova-plugin-geolocation": 5,
       "./cordova-plugin-geolocation.js": 5,
       "./cordova-plugin-file-opener2": 6
   };
   function webpackContext(req) {
       return __webpack_require__(webpackContextResolve(req));
   };
   function webpackContextResolve(req) {
       return map[req] || (function() { throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'.") }());
   };
   webpackContext.keys = function webpackContextKeys() {
       return Object.keys(map);
   };
   webpackContext.resolve = webpackContextResolve;
   module.exports = webpackContext;
   webpackContext.id = 1;
   ```

   /***/ },

   ...

   /***/ function(module, exports) {

   ```
   'use strict';

   exports.install = function (Vue, options, cb) {
     document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

         if (typeof cordova.plugins.fileOpener2 === 'undefined'){
         return cb(false);
         }


       // pass through the geolocation object
         Vue.cordova.fileOpener2 = cordova.plugins.fileOpener2;

       return cb(true);
     }, false);
   };

   /***/ },
   ```
3. added the following to plugins in the data object in app.vue:  (I'm not sure what else to add to this definition.  Any suggestions?)

   'cordova-plugin-file-opener2': function () {
        if (!Vue.cordova.fileOpener2){
        window.alert('Vue.cordova.fileOpener2 not found !')
        return
        }
    }

After taking these three steps, I expect {{ fileOpener2 }} to be available in my template as an object, but it's not.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Did you wait for the `deviceready` event ?

Maybe try to access your plugin once this event has been triggered. Example :

```
Vue.cordova.on('deviceready', () => {
  // here check for your variable
})
```

However it is most likely that you didn't follow the contribution guide to support this plugin as stated by Gandhi over there. You should not edit webpack generated files but rather generate your own :

- clone the `vue-cordova` repo
- replace `node_modules/vue-cordova` in your project with a symlink to the cloned repo
- add the plugins and run `npm run build` (or `npm run dev`)

Then retry to build your Cordova app

Comment: Sorry for the daft questions, I'm new to this.  I'm trying to understand what you mean by 'make a symbolic link' to the cloned repo (and why the repo needs to be cloned at all if it's installed via npm).  As far as I know, I followed your instructions.  I cloned the required plugin into the '@/plugins/' directory and added it to the list of plugins in index.js (see my step #2).  After running npm run build, I still don't have access to the plugin.

Comment: @kartsims same problem with me , i have not changed anything in any files, I just directly used the code , also tried with you above answer , can you please help me solve this

Comment: @kartsims for even on function is not available

Answer (score 0):

For those who can't manage to add Add Cordova plugins to Vue-Cordova, it's a question related to transpile file with Webpack,

1. Clone the repot
2. Create a file named by the plugin in the plugins/ directory
3. Add your plugin to the list in src/index.js
4. Add ".babelrc" in root folder

   Put this

   ```
   {
     "presets": [
       [
         "env",  { "modules": false }
       ]
     ]
   }
   ```
5. Run `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env`
6. Run command `npm install`

You should find the generated transpiled file in root folder index.js

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, replacing this function in cordova.js allows the plugins to load properly...

```
  function findCordovaPath() {
    let platform = cordova.platformId.toUpperCase();
    if (platform === 'ANDROID') {
      return `file:///android_asset/www/`;
    }
    else if (platform === 'IOS') {
      return `cdvfile://localhost/bundle/www/`;
    }
    else if (platform === 'OSX') {
      return `cdvfile://localhost/bundle/Contents/Resources/www/`;
    }
    else if (platform === 'WINDOWS') {
      return `/www/`;
    }
    return null;
  }
```